# REPLACE in Oracle 10g not working as I expected, can anyone explain?

Tags: sql, oracle, string, oracle10g, ora-01403

I am using oracle 10g express.

I have a table named artists_i_hate, I have simplified to illustrate the problem clearer

```
ID | Name       | Opinion
-----------------------------
11 | jamesblunt | i hate him
```

I run the statement

```
SELECT * FROM artists_i_hate WHERE to_char(ID)=REPLACE(to_char(1.1), '.');
```

Why do I get 'no data found' I can't find an explanation anywhere in the documentation.

btw I am aware that the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM artists_i_hate WHERE to_char(ID)=REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(1.1), '[^0-9]');
```

So I am thinking the other statement doesn't work because it doesn't like replacing certain symbols.

edit:

Pending testing on original environment having read first 2 responses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may depend on NLS settings as, in some languages the . is not the decimal separator so to_char(1.1) would NOT give '1.1'

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char(12.34) from dual;

TO_CH
-----
12,34
```

In which case the REPLACE wouldn't change anything and therefore the ID wouldn't match.

PS.
If this is the issue, one fix would be

```
select to_char(1.25,'999.99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can't check the nls_numeric_characters till monday but the db is setup in mexican spanish so I guess there is a possibility this could be the problem, I will let you know

Comment: OK, you have identified the problem and your fix returns the '.' decimal separator which is great, however when I execute the statement: SELECT * FROM artists_i_hate WHERE to_char(ID)=REPLACE(to_char(2.404, '999.99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,'), '.'); it still doesn't return table data for 2404. The following statement does return a value though: SELECT * FROM artists_i_hate WHERE to_char(ID)=REPLACE(to_char(2.404), ','); why is this?

Answer (score 1):

This below shows that there is absolutely no difference between the two expressions. They are completely equivalent so if the REGEXP_REPLACE works, so will the REPLACE.

```
CREATE TABLE tester2 AS
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(1.1), '[^0-9]') Col1,
    REPLACE(to_char(1.1), '.') Col2
from dual;

select * from tester2;    
select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = 'TESTER2';
```

Output:

```
COL1    COL2
11    11

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE  DATA_LENGTH   
TESTER2 COL1        VARCHAR2   2
TESTER2 COL2        VARCHAR2   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually the number I was initially testing was 2.403 with 2403 in the db table but I guess the length shouldn't make a difference. I am unable to re-test till Monday but with check as soon as I can, in the mean time i will mark your answer as correct.